# React JSX in className if-else syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, jsx, classname

I am currently working on a react app where I am adding and changing classes based on certain state changes. It worked successfully in testing with a ternary operator but now I realized I will have to add mutiple else-if statements so I am trying to convert it to a classic if else format but am getting syntax errors and I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is the ternary operator that worked fine:-

```
<div className={"wrapper " + (this.state.hot ? 'wrapper-gradient-hot' : 'wrapper-gradient-cold')}>
```

Here is my attempt to make it a classic if-else in JSX and failed:-

```
<div className={"wrapper " + (
                        if (this.state.hot) {
                            return 'wrapper-gradient-hot';
                        } else {
                            return 'wrapper-gradient-cold';
                        }
                    )}>
```

Pls help me out :)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use expressions inside of a React Component attribute. You'll need to move your logic into a function.

```
function temperatureClassname(temp){
  const prefix = 'wrapper-gradient-'

  switch (temp) {
    case 'hot':      return prefix + 'hot'
    case 'cold':     return prefix + 'cold'
    case 'ice-cold': return prefix + 'too-cool'
  }
}
```

And your react component would look like this:

```
<div className={ temperatureClassname(this.state.hot) }>
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion was just what I needed haha. I almost never use a switch statement but here it’s just perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers =)

Answer (score 4):

If and else statements, are just that... **statements**. Inline JSX expressions that you wrap with `{…}` only allow *expressions*; statements are not expressions.

Your ternary approach is fine, though since there's some commonality between the two strings you can actually use interpolation:

```
<div className={`wrapper-gradient-${this.state.hot ? 'hot' : 'cold'}`}>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could adopt is to handle this **outside** of your JSX. So, in your render function still but just above where you return.

```
render() {
  let gradientValue;
  // Put your if-else here and update gradientValue on each condition.
  return (
    <h1 className=`wrapper ${gradientValue}`>Your html here</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: ``` className={`btn btn-secondary ${currency === 'INR' && 'active'}`}```

Answer (score 0):

`return` only returns values from inside a function, just putting parentheses around an if/else statement like that isn't going to work. You'd be better off sticking with the ternary operator, and nesting them as required.